multidimensional slice access performance in golang
I am working on a little and simple game-of-life in Golang and stumbled on a performance problem during slice access.
This is the primary data structure for the game:
type Neighbor struct {
    X, Y int
}

type Grid struct {
    Data          [][]uint8      // a cell
    NeighborCount [][]int        // how many neighbors a cell has
    Neighbors     [][][]Neighbor // the list of neighbors per cell, setup once during init
    Empty         bool
    Config        *Config
}

So, I already tried to avoid using pointers etc. The slices are being initialized once on startup and never change throughout the game.
Now, when I run the game, it works pretty good, but at grid sizes 1500x1500 and above, performance drops significantly.
I profiled the game and the code which takes the most time by far is the CountNeighbors(x,y) function, which looks like this:
// count the living neighbors of a cell
func (grid *Grid) CountNeighbors(x, y int) uint8 {
    var count uint8

    for idx := 0; idx < grid.NeighborCount[y][x]; idx++ {
        count += grid.Data[grid.Neighbors[y][x][idx].Y][grid.Neighbors[y][x][idx].X]
    }

    return count
}

The game spends 44% of the whole running time in that function. It's really simple, it iterates over all neighbors of a cell and just adds their content because cells are just  uint8s where a living one is signified by 1.
This is what I see in the profiler about that function:
  Total:      22.10s     22.10s (flat, cum) 44.84%
    107            .          .            
    108            .          .           // count the living neighbors of a cell 
    109            .          .           func (grid *Grid) CountNeighbors(x, y int) uint8 { 
    110            .          .             var count uint8 
    111            .          .            
    112        6.59s      6.59s             for idx := 0; idx < grid.NeighborCount[y][x]; idx++ { 
    113       15.51s     15.51s                 count += grid.Data[grid.Neighbors[y][x][idx].Y][grid.Neighbors[y][x][idx].X] 
    114            .          .             } 
    115            .          .            
    116            .          .             return count 
    117            .          .           } 
    118            .          .  

GC does not play any significant role according to the profile. What's also interesting is, the assembly generated for line 113:
230ms      230ms   829cb0:   MOVZX 0(DI)(R13*1), R13      grid.go:113
                      ⋮
190ms      190ms   829cb8:   ADDL R13, DX                 grid.go:113
                      ⋮
250ms      250ms   829cf8:   MOVQ 0x38(SI), R13           grid.go:113
100ms      100ms   829cfc:   NOPL 0(AX)                   grid.go:113
670ms      670ms   829d00:   CMPQ R13, AX                 grid.go:113
    .          .   829d03:   JBE 0x829ddc                 grid.go:113
 70ms       70ms   829d09:   MOVQ 0x30(SI), R13           grid.go:113
210ms      210ms   829d0d:   MOVQ 0x8(R13)(R11*8), R15    grid.go:113
190ms      190ms   829d12:   MOVQ 0(R13)(R11*8), R13      grid.go:113
640ms      640ms   829d17:   NOPW 0(AX)(AX*1)             grid.go:113
 20ms       20ms   829d20:   CMPQ CX, R15                 grid.go:113
    .          .   829d23:   JAE 0x829dd1                 grid.go:113
260ms      260ms   829d29:   LEAQ 0(CX)(CX*2), R15        grid.go:113
 40ms       40ms   829d2d:   MOVQ 0x8(R13)(R15*8), DI     grid.go:113
1.27s      1.27s   829d32:   MOVQ 0(R13)(R15*8), R13      grid.go:113
200ms      200ms   829d37:   NOPW 0(AX)(AX*1)             grid.go:113
150ms      150ms   829d40:   CMPQ BX, DI                  grid.go:113
    .          .   829d43:   JAE 0x829dc6                 grid.go:113
150ms      150ms   829d49:   LEAQ 0(BX)(BX*2), DI         grid.go:113
570ms      570ms   829d4d:   MOVQ 0x8(R13)(DI*8), R15     grid.go:113
5.69s      5.69s   829d52:   CMPQ R15, R9                 grid.go:113
    .          .   829d55:   JAE 0x829dbb                 grid.go:113
820ms      820ms   829d57:   LEAQ 0(R15)(R15*2), R15      grid.go:113
 20ms       20ms   829d5b:   MOVQ 0x8(R10)(R15*8), R12    grid.go:113
   3s         3s   829d60:   MOVQ 0(R13)(DI*8), DI        grid.go:113
170ms      170ms   829d65:   MOVQ 0(R10)(R15*8), R13      grid.go:113
600ms      600ms   829d69:   CMPQ DI, R12                 grid.go:113
    .          .   829d6c:   JB 0x829cb0                  grid.go:113
    .          .   829d72:   JMP 0x829db0                 grid.go:113
                      ⋮
    .          .   829db0:   MOVQ DI, AX                  grid.go:113
    .          .   829db3:   MOVQ R12, CX                 grid.go:113
    .          .   829db6:   CALL runtime.panicIndex(SB)  grid.go:113
    .          .   829dbb:   MOVQ R15, AX                 grid.go:113
    .          .   829dbe:   MOVQ R9, CX                  grid.go:113
    .          .   829dc1:   CALL runtime.panicIndex(SB)  grid.go:113
    .          .   829dc6:   MOVQ BX, AX                  grid.go:113
    .          .   829dc9:   MOVQ DI, CX                  grid.go:113
    .          .   829dcc:   CALL runtime.panicIndex(SB)  grid.go:113
    .          .   829dd1:   MOVQ CX, AX                  grid.go:113
    .          .   829dd4:   MOVQ R15, CX                 grid.go:113
    .          .   829dd7:   CALL runtime.panicIndex(SB)  grid.go:113
    .          .   829ddc:   MOVQ R13, CX                 grid.go:113
    .          .   829ddf:   NOPL                         grid.go:113
    .          .   829de0:   CALL runtime.panicIndex(SB)  grid.go:113

This is a lot of stuff for my taste.
However. I don't understand why go wastes so much time during simple slice access. I also tried to use an array [2]int to store the neighbor position instead of the struct Neighbor shown above. But the result ist the same.
One last thing: I am using goroutines during cell state calculation (of which the stuff outlined above is part of): one goroutine per row to be precise, without locking. This works because the slices are only accessed for reading. However, I also tried it without goroutines. Then the whole game is slower (25 FPS vs. 40 FPS with goroutines), but it spends less time in CountNeighbors(): only 22%. But the multidimensional slice access is still the bottle neck.
So, what is going on here and how (if possible) can I speed this up?
PS: the whole source can be seen here

edited to add (2024/07/16): I followed the advice of @eik and @kostic and turned the grid into a one dimensional slice:
type Grid struct {
    Data          []uint8
    NeighborCount []int
    Neighbors     [][]Neighbor
    Empty         bool
    Config        *Config
}

I access the elements as suggested:
    // first setup the cells
    for y := 0; y < config.Height; y++ {
        for x := 0; x < config.Width; x++ {
            grid.Data[y+STRIDE*x] = 0
        }
    }

the variable STRIDE is either the grid width or height, whatever is larger.
Here's the updated counter function:
func (grid *Grid) CountNeighbors(x, y int) uint8 {
    var count uint8

    pos := y + STRIDE*x
    neighbors := grid.Neighbors[pos]
    neighborCount := grid.NeighborCount[pos]

    for idx := 0; idx < neighborCount; idx++ {
        neighbor := neighbors[idx]
        count += grid.Data[neighbor.Y+STRIDE*neighbor.X]
    }

    return count
}

When I run this with the known settings (1500*1500 grid) the game runs at approximately 30 FPS - slower than before. The bottleneck is still the function CountNeighbors, but it looks worse.
Here's the view of the profiler (the function is the top offender):

  Total:      79.53s     79.53s (flat, cum) 58.42%
    104            .          .           // count the living neighbors of a cell 
    105            .          .           func (grid *Grid) CountNeighbors(x, y int) uint8 { 
    106            .          .             var count uint8 
    107            .          .            
    108            .          .             pos := y + STRIDE*x 
    109       41.80s     41.80s             neighbors := grid.Neighbors[pos] 
    110       12.21s     12.21s             neighborCount := grid.NeighborCount[pos] 
    111            .          .            
    112       17.01s     17.01s             for idx := 0; idx < neighborCount; idx++ { 
    113        1.66s      1.66s                 neighbor := neighbors[idx] 
    114        6.85s      6.85s                 count += grid.Data[neighbor.Y+STRIDE*neighbor.X] 
    115            .          .             } 
    116            .          .            
    117            .          .             return count 
    118            .          .           } 
    119            .          .       


Update: I also tried to calculate the neighbor states directly and not using the neighbor arrays as suggested by @paul-hankin. This is the function:
func (grid *Grid) CountNeighbors(x, y int) uint8 {
    var sum uint8

    width := grid.Config.Width
    height := grid.Config.Height

    for nbgX := -1; nbgX < 2; nbgX++ {
        for nbgY := -1; nbgY < 2; nbgY++ {
            var col, row int

            xnbgX := x + nbgX
            ynbgY := y + nbgY

            // In traditional grid mode the edges are deadly
            if xnbgX < 0 || xnbgX >= width || ynbgY < 0 || ynbgY >= height {
                continue
            }
            col = xnbgX
            row = ynbgY

            sum += grid.Data[row+STRIDE*col]
        }
    }

    // don't count ourselfes though
    sum -= grid.Data[y+STRIDE*x]

    return sum
}

With this things get a little better, the game starts at 42FPS, but drops to 30-35FPS after 10-20 seconds. Profile:
  Total:      18.76s     18.76s (flat, cum) 29.19%
    130            .          .             sum -= grid.Data[y+STRIDE*x] 
    131            .          .            
    132            .          .             return sum 
    133            .          .           } 
    134            .          .            
    135        270ms      270ms           func (grid *Grid) CountNeighbors(x, y int) uint8 { 
    136            .          .             var sum uint8 
    137            .          .            
    138         30ms       30ms             width := grid.Config.Width 
    139        340ms      340ms             height := grid.Config.Height 
    140            .          .            
    141        680ms      680ms             for nbgX := -1; nbgX < 2; nbgX++ { 
    142        820ms      820ms                 for nbgY := -1; nbgY < 2; nbgY++ { 
    143            .          .                     var col, row int 
    144            .          .            
    145         50ms       50ms                     xnbgX := x + nbgX 
    146        760ms      760ms                     ynbgY := y + nbgY 
    147            .          .            
    148            .          .                     // In traditional grid mode the edges are deadly 
    149        1.44s      1.44s                     if xnbgX < 0 || xnbgX >= width || ynbgY < 0 || ynbgY >= height { 
    150            .          .                         continue 
    151            .          .                     } 
    152            .          .                     col = xnbgX 
    153            .          .                     row = ynbgY 
    154            .          .            
    155       13.67s     13.67s                     sum += grid.Data[row+STRIDE*col] 
    156            .          .                 } 
    157            .          .             } 
    158            .          .            
    159            .          .             // don't count ourselfes though 
    160        520ms      520ms             sum -= grid.Data[y+STRIDE*x] 
    161            .          .            
    162        180ms      180ms             return sum 
    163            .          .           } 

Still, the most expensive call is sum += grid.Data[row+STRIDE*col]. Yes, there's branching in the function and there might be a way of eliminating it (my solution to this was the neighbor list I've used so far, described above). But it consumes only 0.42%, which is negligible (at this point at least, for me).
It's a mystery :(

Go does not have multidimensional slices. In your code, you're dealing with slices of slices. If you want better data locality, you might employ the technique known, say, in C: have a single slice partitioned in logical "strides". Calculating the index given X, Y would be Y * stride_size + X.

Yes, data locality could be thrashing your cache. If there are a lot of slice accesses, you could try disabling bounds checking to see how much of an impact that is making (using a single large slice might allow the compiler to optimize that out anyway)

Assuming your grid is actually a grid, I'd try computing the set of neighbours in code rather than looking them up in a huge precomputed table. You're wasting the memory cache on this useless data.

@PaulHankin: I did it that way in a previous version and it was much slower. I had to access the grid eight times per cell. And since I know the neighbor positions in advance, why re-calculating it every tick for every cell - was my thought.

@Tom the calculation should be approximately 1 machine cycle. If you have a contiguous array, the neighbours are at fixed offsets from the current position. Avoid edge-cases either by padding your grid by 1 at the edges or handling the edges with separate general-purpose code and treat the majority of the grid (each cell having exactly 8 neighbours) with high-performance hard-coded neighbour offsets.

You might find these resources useful: https://www.dataorienteddesign.com/site.php . Much of these links are talking about C++, but the principles of efficient code apply equally to go too.

When you are performance constrained, you'll want to keep an eye on access patterns and arrange your data considering temporal and spatial locality for fast cache access. Also, multiple bounds checking on every index is probably not what you want.
If you can, try one single array accessed by a[x + N * y], depending on your loop order. Profiling (what you already do) is a good idea.

Ok, I see. So I'll try this tomorrow. However, doesn't it cost much CPU time to do this calculation in each iteration?

@Tom: Negligible compared to a cache miss.  Especially if you're looping so y*N is loop-invariant when the inner loop increments x, so it can actually just increment a pointer by 4 or 8 or something.  (Assuming the Go compiler is smart enough; C compilers are.)  Even incrementing y is just adding N*4 or whatever to the address, or it might redo the calculation if x also resets, instead of subtracting and adding.  (Turning a multiply by a loop counter into addition is called strength-reduction optimization.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strength_reduction)

I tried more variations, please see the updated question above. tl;dr: by just using a single slice as suggested it gets worse. If I do not use the pre-computed neighbors list but calculate neighbor state at each tick, then it gets a little better, but not by much.
